# loading a csv into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I have the following code to load csv's into mysql.

```
SET @count = 0;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'TELE_AFC_03.03.2014.csv'
INTO TABLE failure_report.master_entry
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
ignore 2 rows
(@sno,@var1,line,section,station,system,sub_system,equipment,sub_equipment,failure_time,rectified_time,duration,failure_description,rectification,lmd,origin,attended_by,reported_by,urr)
set id = (@count :=@count+1), failure_date =STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%c/%e/%Y');
```

It is working fine for some files but for some csv's it gives an error

```
Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns
```

although all files have same number of columns.
This csv gives error
http://speedy.sh/bSDTE/TELE-AFC-05.03.2014.csv
while this csv works fine although both have same columns
http://speedy.sh/h4cVt/TELE-AFC-03.03.2014.csv

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example line that is failing please? So line 1 of the CSV that fails in the example in the OP.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i have included the csv's

Comment: What line is the linked errored CSV failing on?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR the error is about excess columns so it fails on the first row of data(i ignore the first two rows of every csv to ignore heading and column names)

Comment: Have a look at data rows of both files: All lines of the working csv end with `,UR` All data lines of the non working csv end with `,UR,,`. So much for the difference.

Comment: Just spotted it too, @VMai is right, you've got 2 extra empty columns in your failing templates.